# How to reference header files in Bridging-Header.h after updating CocoaPods to 0.36.x and above?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

After updating to CocoaPods 0.36.x, I am unable to add imports into my Bridging-Header.h file. I get the "DBSphereView.h file not found".

The file is indeed present in:

```
"Pods/DBSphereTagCloud/DBSphereView.h"
"Headers/public/DBSphereTagCloud/DBSphereView.h"
"Headers/private/DBSphereTagCloud/DBSphereView.h"
```

My bridge file:

```
#ifndef Loan_Bridging_Header_h
#define Loan_Bridging_Header_h
#import "DBSphereView.h"
#endif
```

I am able to use Frameworks. I have a reference to a well known Framework (Alamofire), and it works great!

My podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
pod 'DBSphereTagCloud', '~> 1.0'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.1'
```

Before updating, I had no problems with importing header files.

How do I reference header files in Bridging-Header.h after updating CocoaPods to 0.36.x?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I also tried to create a separate project based on the example "Get Started" from cocoapods.org, without success. After using Frameworks, I can't seem to reference header files in my bridging header file. I must be missing some detail?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

In your `Podfile`, you specified `use_frameworks!`.

As a result, the Objective-C code you're including as a dependency (`DBSphereTagCloud`) is packaged as a framework, instead of a static library. Please see [CocoaPods 0.36 - Framework and Swift Support](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/) for more details.

As a consequence, you don't need a bridging header file. It's enough for you to add:

```
import DBSphereTagCloud
```

in all the Swift files that need that module.

Comment: How to import,  if i have mix Objective-C & swift files in my project and want to use DBSphereTagCloud.h ?

Comment: For swift file i can successfully import  DBSphereTagCloud.h [ as you suggest import DBSphereTagCloud ] but for Objective-C file ?

Comment: Was scratching my head on this one when Ventokenfield wasn't working anymore.  Thanks!

Comment: OMG, i've been having this problem in random projects for weeks.  Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 53):

I had problems with this. My bridging header wasn't finding pod libs. I ended up finding out that I have to do this.

[image]

Comment: I was having trouble with a framework after turning on use_frameworks! I was getting the error "MTLModel.h not found" in an obj-c class that was referenced in my bridging header. Adding Pods to the User Header Search paths, as this answer says to do, resolved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
import  <DBSphereTagCloud/DBSphereView.h>
import  <DBSphereTagCloud/DBSphereView.h>
```

Answer (score -1):

For me...

Original

```
import  "<Folder/File.h>"
```

Change to

```
import  <Folder/File.h>
```

Answer (score -1):

In Project > Build Settings > Search Paths > Header Search Paths

Add:

"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/[Name of folder which pod files are contained in]"

Do that for every pod you installed