# Unable to build ScanApiSdk with error ScanApiHelper.h file not found

Tags: swift, socketscan

I am attempting to add in the Socket Mobile ScanApiSdk into my project but it is failing to build with the error '**ScanApiHelper.h**' file not found.  I have installed it into my project workspace using the **CocoaPods** method.  Unzipped the SDK into a folder at the same folder level as my project folder.   Adding the following line to my Podfile.

```
pod 'ScanAPI', :path => '../scanapisdk'
```

Then ran the pod install command at prompt.   Launched project from the **xcworkspace** file and then added the following line to my bridging header.

```
#import "ScanApiHelper.h"
```

Build fails at this line in the bridging header.

> Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a)
>
> gem --version 2.0.14.1
>
> pod --version 1.0.1
>
> ScanAPI SDK Version 10.3.55

I was able to download the sample SingleEntrySwift project from Github, build it, and load it on my iPhone for testing.

Can someone help point out what I am doing wrong in my own project or troubleshooting steps?

Comment: Are all the files from the SDK zip, e.g. `ScanAPI.podspec` and `ScanApiHelper.h`, inside `scanapisdk` or are they in a folder nested inside it? Can you try using the absolute path to your ScanAPI directory?

Comment: All files are in the base scanapisdk folder, there is no sub-folder.   I just tried using the absolute path to the scanapisdk but it still failed to build.   The pod is being installed successfully.  I can see it under the Pods tree in my project navigator, under Development Pods and then ScanAPI.  There I see the ScanApiHelper.h

Comment: Can you make sure that the path to your bridging header file is set under `XCode -> Build Settings`?

Comment: The bridging header file was not in the build settings, but I have other libraries in the bridging header that are compiling properly.  I went ahead and added it however the issue is still not resolved.   I did notice some settings in the Pods-{appname}.release.xconfig file from the sample github project which are not in my project.

Comment: Disregard the comment about settings found in xconfig I found them in the ScanAPI.xconfig under Support Files for the ScanAPI development pod

Comment: Hmm... this is quite strange. Can you compare [this project](http://www.filedropper.com/testsdktodelete) to your project? It was created from scratch using XCode 8. In `BridgingHeader.h` it says `#include ScanApiHelper.h`, but `#import` worked too

Comment: Your testSdkToDelete compiled just fine after I pointed the pod file to my copy of the SDK and ran pod install.   I also created my own project from scratch and was able to get it to build.   So it is just my actual development project I cannot get it added to.  All I can think to do is rebuild my application from a new project but I would really prefer to avoid that.

Comment: This is getting pretty infuriating.  I can get it to build in anything but my own project with the only difference being my project was created in Xcode 7.3

Comment: That's understandable. Can you email developers@socketmobile.com and include some more details about your setup and when it started to fail? For instance, did you only upgrade xcode or did you migrate from swift 2 to swift 3 at the same time? Which other pods do you have installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue too and this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29094237/44816) worked for me.

Basically, you don't need a bridging header if you use `use_frameworks!`. Instead you just `import ScanAPI` in any swift files that use ScanAPI.

Comment: Yes this was the exact solution.   Discovered it just a little bit ago when troubleshooting with a developer from socket mobile.  Thank you for posting!