# #import file not found error in cocoaPods when using ObjectiveC in Swift project

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I install an Objective C pod to my swift 3 project.  I include “use_frameworks” in the Podfile so I don’t need to add anything to my bridging header.

The problem is when I include a (third party) generated ObjectiveC file that attempts to #import a header from the pod - it fails with “‘[xxxxx].h’ file not found”

The ObjectiveC #import "GTLRObject.h" statement causes "GTLRObject.h file not found" error.

My Podfile:

```
target 'myHelloWorld' do
 # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
 use_frameworks!
 pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST'
end
```

Bridging header.  I need to include the header for the generated ObjectiveC class so I can use it in my swift code :

```
#import "GTLREcho.h"
```

GTLREcho.h:

```
// NOTE: This file was generated by the ServiceGenerator.

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// API:
//   echo/v1
// Description:
//   This is an API

#import "GTLREchoObjects.h"
#import "GTLREchoQuery.h"
#import "GTLREchoService.h"
```

Error is in GTLREchoObjects.h.  #import "GTLRObject.h" = **"'GTLRObject.h'  file not found"**:

```
#if GTLR_BUILT_AS_FRAMEWORK
   #import "GTLR/GTLRObject.h"
#else
   #import "GTLRObject.h"
#endif
```

If I try and reference GTLRObject from a swift file I don't get any error e.g.

```
import Foundation
import GoogleAPIClientForREST

class ControllerHello: NSObject {

func sayHello(strTest: String){
    let gtlObject = GTLRObject
    }
}
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Updating User Header Search Paths seemed to resolve this. See [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080026/how-to-reference-header-files-in-bridging-header-h-after-updating-cocoapods-to-0)

Answer (score 6):

Since this answer might be useful for others.

When using `GoogleAPIClientForREST`:

Open `TARGETS` > `App` > `Build Settings`

For `User Header Search Paths` add `Pods` and select `recursive`.

[image]

Comment: `$(inherited)` as recursive, worked for me